# meshlabserver : vertex attribute transfer

Tags: mesh, 3d-reconstruction, meshlab

I want to automate the reconstruction from colored pointcloud. I have the meshlab script which cleans noise by some thresholding and it also cleans scattered noise. Then it does poisson reconstruction. Now I want to transfer color from pointcloud to newly generated poisson mesh. With meshlab GUI, vertex attribute transfer is working fine, but it's not working with meshlabserver script.

Here is my meshlabscript:

```
<!DOCTYPE FilterScript>
<FilterScript>
 <filter name="Conditional Vertex Selection">
  <Param type="RichString" value="x &lt; -1.16" name="condSelect"/>
  <Param type="RichBool" value="true" name="strictSelect"/>
 </filter>
 <filter name="Delete Selected Vertices"/>
 <filter name="Conditional Vertex Selection">
  <Param type="RichString" value="y &lt; -0.5" name="condSelect"/>
  <Param type="RichBool" value="true" name="strictSelect"/>
 </filter>
 <filter name="Delete Selected Vertices"/>
 <filter name="Conditional Vertex Selection">
  <Param type="RichString" value="z > 2.3" name="condSelect"/>
  <Param type="RichBool" value="true" name="strictSelect"/>
     </filter>
 <filter name="Delete Selected Vertices"/>
 <filter name="Conditional Vertex Selection">
  <Param type="RichString" value="z &lt; 1" name="condSelect"/>
  <Param type="RichBool" value="true" name="strictSelect"/>
 </filter>
 <filter name="Delete Selected Vertices"/>
 <filter name="Estimate radius from density">
  <Param type="RichInt" value="40" name="NbNeighbors"/>
 </filter>
 <filter name="Conditional Vertex Selection">
  <Param type="RichString" value="rad > 0.012" name="condSelect"/>
  <Param type="RichBool" value="true" name="strictSelect"/>
 </filter>
 <filter name="Delete Selected Vertices"/>
 <filter name="Compute normals for point sets">
  <Param type="RichInt" value="10" name="K"/>
  <Param type="RichBool" value="false" name="flipFlag"/>
  <Param x="0" y="0" z="0" type="RichPoint3f" name="viewPos"/>
 </filter>
 <filter name="Surface Reconstruction: Poisson">
  <Param type="RichInt" value="8" name="OctDepth"/>
  <Param type="RichInt" value="8" name="SolverDivide"/>
  <Param type="RichFloat" value="1" name="SamplesPerNode"/>
  <Param type="RichFloat" value="1" name="Offset"/>
 </filter>
 <filter name="Vertex Attribute Transfer">
  <Param type="RichMesh" value="1" name="SourceMesh"/>
  <Param type="RichMesh" value="0" name="TargetMesh"/>
  <Param type="RichBool" value="false" name="GeomTransfer"/>
  <Param type="RichBool" value="false" name="NormalTransfer"/>
  <Param type="RichBool" value="true" name="ColorTransfer"/>
  <Param type="RichBool" value="false" name="QualityTransfer"/>
  <Param type="RichBool" value="false" name="SelectionTransfer"/>
  <Param type="RichBool" value="false" name="QualityDistance"/>
  <Param type="RichAbsPerc" value="0.042202" min="0" name="UpperBound" max="2.11009"/>
 </filter>
</FilterScript>
```

How to make it working ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug. When I follow the cleaning and reconstruction process in the meshlab, it worked. But I save the script and ran using command line, it didn't work. The problem was wrong ordering of meshes in vertex attribute transfer. I switched the value of source and target mesh in vertex attribute transfer part of the script and it worked.